# Error Manager: from standard Java to Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, class, servlets

I've created my Logger Java class, for a private use webapp, using JSP/servlet.

My logger class write errors on a custom file, but I also need to let them appear as a javascript window allert.

I was going to use a simple

```
out.println(message_error_containing_javascript);
```

but of course it doesn't work (I can't even compile).

So I was thinking about launching a Servlet from a standard java class.

Is that possible? If not, is there any not-so-complex solution to solve this issue?

Comment: How about `alert (error_ms);`

Comment: can you be more specific plese?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't just "launch a servlet" from a regular Java class. In fact you'd have to define what "launch" means, since it's not something you do to servlets.

You would need a centralized logging system that would get all the messages, then intercepts the HTML output during view rendering phase and inserts the javascript accordingly.

However this might not be the not-so-complex solution you're looking for.

Edit:
I'm assuming you're in a situation as follows, and wish to somehow display the exception to the user? (Ok, you are)

```
public class MyNonServletClass {
    public void method() {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            myLogger.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You would need some mechanism that runs at the display time, checks whether there are messages that need to be displayed, and displays them. JSF would have a ready made mechanism for that, but with JSP you'll have to do it yourself.

You could for example include a JSP fragment on each page, that will check the session for the logger and display any messages that are marked as such. However, as I said, you'll need to do some work for this.

Comment: but what if my errors are something that I'm managing on java? Like exceptions and custom errors that did not appear on the webpage?

Comment: You'll need to keep track of them yourself and make your Logging System know about them. The Logging System can then hook up to a web page and display those errors, if that makes sense. Your question is quite broad, can you update the post with an example?

Comment: it's the situation you've explained in your answer